# Security level of local database in html5

Tags: html, security

I am using **html5** local database for storing some credential.so far i know how to store/access variable and database table in local database.

The problem is,as i'm storing some user credential there,i am not sure how secure it is.

for example: `window.localStorage.setItem('value', area.value);` stores `area.value` to `value` variable.

and for accessing that item, `window.localStorage.getItem('value')` is used.

Is it possible to track the data of local database without knowing table information(or variable information in above case) when external party can use same computer used by user.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903608/html5-web-database-security).not clear though.

Thanks For stopping by...!!!

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can get and sdet values to the localStorage like an array: `localStorage["mykey"]`. The `window.` bit is not necessary either.

Comment: there are no database table in localStorage. This is key-value storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should't store credentials in your local database.

You can track it with this code

```
for (var key in window.localStorage){
    console.log("Key:", key);
    console.log("Value:", window.localStorage[key]);
}
```

It should work in most browsers.
Security violation can be done for example by XSS.

Comment: I know the fact that if i know variable name or table name,i can access the data.i was asking about without knowing information of variables or tables.

Comment: with this for loop you can get you all the keys/data from localstorage without knowledge of any variables.

Comment: it only returns key.not value associated with it.

Comment: as long as you know key name you can easily get the value. I've updated the code.